# How can I make background image covered by dots on PHP?

Tags: php

I want to make background image with the points on. Sorry I cannot explain it. I do not have enought reputation for the attaching image. Please visit: << [hisset.in](http://www.hisset.in) >> and watch to the background images

Comment: Is this your site - what do you want to accomplish? Do you mean the effect on the image in the background?

Comment: @NicholasPickering yes! How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTML and CSS question.

Use two divs, one for the background and another for the dots layer.

```
.background {
  heigth: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('path/to/my/background.png');
}

.dots {
  heigth: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('path/to/my/dotslayer.png') repeat; //repeat the image all over the div
}
```

And use this image as 'dotslayer' (or another similar): http://www.hisset.in/images/dark/backgroundOverlay.png